# Go GC strange behavior

Tags: go, garbage-collection

We have several services written in Go. After running for several weeks we find that occasionally the heap size keeps increasing.  We added some instrumentation to find out that this is due to a reduction is GC frequency.

We are using Go 1.8. I am not sure if this is a bug in Go GC or something that we have written is triggering this behavior. Any pointers, tips would be helpful.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The gctrace output should show you when and why the GC is running. Is the number of goroutines increasing? This also looks like there could be a resource leak of some sort.

Comment: we track number of go routines, and that is not increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Never guess bad performance reasons before profiling.  Here are instruments https://golang.org/doc/diagnostics.html#profiling